# Iterations to delete node and its children in a binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, graph-algorithm

[Example Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/692zX.png)

Given a binary tree and pointer to a node (which is present) in tree, assume we have parent pointers. I have to find the number of iterations to delete the adjacent nodes and subsequent adjacent nodes of that deleted nodes. Here deleting means setting some flag, node -> burn. I wont delete the node.
Example :

```
         1
       /   \
      2     3
     / \   / \
    4   5 6  7
   /   / 
  8   9
 /
10
```

and given node in tree is 4,

The burned nodes in each iteration

In iteration 1:

- For node 4:  4,8,2 (8 is the child node, 2 is parent of 4 , these are the adjacent nodes of 4).

In iteration 2:

- For node 8: 10 will be burned. (4 is already burned)
- For node 2: 5 and 1 will be burned.

This continues... , hence i have to find the number of iterations required to burn all nodes.

Comment: @JimMischel, Thanks for pointing it out, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not efficient but I think it will work:

Maintain a queue for the next nodes to be considered for deletion. And before deleting a node's adjacent nodes check whether they already have `burn` flag set.

Also, every time when you remove an item from queue:

- check if all the nodes are burned or not (for this you can maintain a
  `Hash` for faster access)
- increment iteration count(which will be your result)

Comment: It will work i guess, instead of maintaining hash we can use a flag(queue can contain Tree node and flag) which denotes end of iteration. i.e., set a flag to the last enqueued adjacent node of adjacent nodes, when we dequeue that node we can increment count.